# Issue with remote deployment of *.apk app using Airwatch

Tags: android, deployment, mdm, motorola, airwatch

I'm going through some hard times to remotely publish an in-house developed app over VMWare Airwatch application.

The application is published via Airwatch Console and then delivered to the smartphone...so far, so good. However when the user attempts to install it, android always raises the same message: "error during the package analysis" (in free translation to english. The original message language is Spanish, as you can see below).

The original message is raised in Spanish: "Se produjo un error durante el análisis del paquete".

Our mobile devices have the latest Airwatch Agent version 5.3.0.724 published to PlayStore. The only way our app can be deployed is over Airwatch, since it's a corporate mobile used by frontline employees, therefore access to apps has been supressed as well as data transfers (to preserve the 3G/4G franchises and avoid extra charges).

The issue reported happens both in smartphones factory restored (only with Airwatch app installed) and smartphones with the company required image.

The mobile devices are Moto-E 2nd generation using Lollipop 5.0.2

I'm looking for some help since I'm an IT project manager and this is a big risk to our corporate project.

I also have some logs from Airwatch console, which are quite long to post right. Should someone require, I can paste into the thread.

Thx and Brs,

Joao Kraemer.

Comment: Have you tried to manually install your app on a smartphone (better if it is the same model) without AirWatch? Does it work?

Comment: Are you installing an internal application or public application? You can always contact airwatch support team for help.